# HttpListenerContext.Request.InputStream always null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, httplistener

I send a request on port 60080

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.open('GET', 'http://localhost:60080/api/products');
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
XHR.body = JSON.stringify({ email: "hello@user.com", response: { name: "Tester" } });
XHR.send();
```

and receive it using HttpListener

```
this.listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:60080/");
listener.Start();
listener.BeginGetContext(HandleRequest, listener);
```

so i get HttpListenerContext

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
```

When i try to get InputStream (on Android or UWP) it is constantly null. `ContentLength = 0;`
When i test on iOS InputStream not null and `ContentLength > 0;`

What is my problem?

**UPDATE:**

I solved my problem.

The fact that I sent a Post method, but actually came method OPTIONS.

I sent the headers in a response and then came the Post method

```
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
httpListenerContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
```

Comment: Where does each part of the code run? First part looks like JavaScript, this is invoked where?

Comment: Yes, the first part of this js. It is called when the application is launched in a webview. HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result); called in HandleRequest. I solved my problem. See update.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer instead and accept it after 24 hours?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

The fact that I sent a Post method, but actually came method OPTIONS.

this is due to CORS tehnology.

I sent the headers in a response and then came the Post method

```
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
httpListenerContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
httpListenerContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
```